# What is wrong with this proof? Is $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}/\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, quotient-spaces, fake-proofs

Let $\pi: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}, x \mapsto x+\mathbb{Q}$ be the canonical projection map. Set
$$\{1,\sqrt{2}\}/\mathbb{Q}:= \pi(\{1,\sqrt{2}\}) = \{1+\mathbb{Q},\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$$
with subspace topology.

Define the map $f:\{1+\mathbb{Q},\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}\}\to \mathbb{R}$ by $1+\mathbb{Q} \mapsto 1$ and $\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}\mapsto \sqrt{2}$. Then $f$ is continuous by the universal property of quotient topology because the inclusion
$$\iota: \{1,\sqrt{2}\}+ \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},\ x \mapsto x$$
is continuous,
$$\pi|_{\{1,\sqrt{2}\}+ \mathbb{Q}}: \{1,\sqrt{2}\}+ \mathbb{Q} \to \{1,\sqrt{2}\}/\mathbb{Q}$$ is a quotient map, because it is open, surjective and continuous, and
$f\circ \pi|_{\{1,\sqrt{2}\}+ \mathbb{Q}} = \iota$.

Where is this "proof" wrong?

My "proof" cannot be true, since $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}/\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ has the trivial topology, but it should be discrete, if $f$ were continuous.

I know that is a silly question, but I cannot see at the moment where I am wrong?

Comment: what is the space $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}/\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: And what does $\pi(\{1, \sqrt 2\}) $ mean?

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  How does $\mathbb Q$ act on a set of two elements?

Comment: What topology are you putting on the set with two elements?

Comment: @lulu the subset topology from $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes, I deleted that comment.  I meant the indiscrete topology.  Only the empty set and the total set are open.  Though in that case, the inclusion map into $\mathbb R$ is discontinuous.

Comment: @lulu right. But my "proof" says that it should be continuous, because of the universal property of quotient map?

Comment: I can't follow your argument.  There isn't a continuous injection of $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ into $\mathbb R$.  Your notation is unusual and hard to follow.

Comment: @lulu I edited the question. I know there is no embdding of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ into $\mathbb{R}$, so my "proof" must be wrong, but I really dont see where I am wrong....

Comment: The paragraph starting “Define the map” is very unclear. $f:A\supseteq B\to…$ is not normal notation.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss I edited it. But, by the way, I think it is normal notation, for example functional analysis with unbounded linear operators and domain?

Comment: Is $\{1,\sqrt{2}\} + \mathbb{Q}$ supposed to be the same two-element set $\{1+\mathbb{Q}, \sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}\}$?

Comment: @aschepler no. $\{1, \sqrt{2}\} + \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q} \cup (\sqrt{2} + \mathbb{Q})$. So $\{1, \sqrt{2}\} + \mathbb{Q} \subseteq{R}$ and $\{1+\mathbb{Q}, \sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: But that’s not the context here. Transplanting a notation designed for one field to another is confusing.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss I try to be more precise next time.

Comment: You have the universal property backwards. It’s about maps from the original space to another space factoring through the quotient space.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss John Doe found my stupid mistake (see comment under answer). It is simply $f\circ \pi|_{\{1,\sqrt{2}\}+ \mathbb{Q}}\neq \iota$....

Comment: Ah. I thought you meant $\{1,\sqrt2\}+\mathbb{Q}$ was what John Doe called $B$, since you said the composition was the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotient topology on $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Q}$ induced by $\pi$ is the indiscrete topology.  Its only open sets are $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Q}$ and $\emptyset$.  If you take $B=\{1+\Bbb{Q},\sqrt{2}+\Bbb{Q}\}$, as a subspace of $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Q}$, it also has the indiscrete topology where its only open sets are $B$ and $\emptyset$.  The map $f:B\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $f(1+\Bbb{Q})=1$ and $f(\sqrt{2}+\Bbb{Q}) = \sqrt{2}$ is discontinuous because $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$ have the discrete topology as a subset of $\Bbb{R}$.  So $f^{-1}(\{1\})=\{1+\Bbb{Q}\}$ and $f^{-1}(\{\sqrt{2}\})=\{\sqrt{2}+\Bbb{Q}\}$ are not open subsets of $B$ - which they should be.

Comment: Yes. That is my contradiction which I already saw. But do you know where exactly my "proof" fails? Sorry, if it is a dumb question. But I really dont see it ....

Comment: @psl2Z: Your proof fails in $f\circ \pi|_{\{1,\sqrt{2}\}+ \mathbb{Q}} \ne \iota$.

Comment: Thank you!! That was a really stupid mistake, but I really did not see it! It is with $0\neq q \in \mathbb{Q}$ arbitrary $f\circ \pi|_{\{1,\sqrt{2}\}+ \mathbb{Q}}(1+q) = f((1+q)+\mathbb{Q}) = f(1 +\mathbb{Q}) = 1 \neq \iota(1+q)$.